# Why was my change rejected?

Tags: support, tags, suggested-edits

I made a suggested edit here: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3804384

removing the iPhone tag as the question didn't relate to iPhone. The edit was rejected by "Community", but the same edit was made later (https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21114682/revisions) by https://stackoverflow.com/users/610351/geoffroy

Just wondering why my edit to remove the tag wasn't good enough, while Geoffroy's was?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another user with more than 2k reputation made [another edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21114682/4) after you submitted yours and before it was reviewed.  In such cases the user with full editing privileges "wins" the edit conflict; yours is automatically rejected by the community user and his is applied.

Comment: So instead of accepting my edit of removing a tag - so I could get credit for it - he does the edit and takes the credit. Nice.

Comment: @JohnT The user had no idea that you made an edit, what it was, or that his edit rejected it.  He just saw a post and edited it at around the same time as you and, because he has full edit privileges and you don't, his edit "won" the conflict.  Had he intentionally made the decision to reject your edit it would have indicated the rejection on the suggested edit page.